# Multilinear Algebra Proof of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, modules, multilinear-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem given in Section 4 of [this](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/332/28ch.pdf) document.

On pg. 4 of the document, there is a line which reads:

> From general multilinear algebra, we know that an action of $R$ on $M$ induces an adjugate action on $M$ as well. For each $r\in R$, the adjugate $r^{adj}$ need not lie in the subring $\text{End}_{k[x]}M$ of $R$, nor need it commute with $R$.

I do not know anything about the adjugate action the author has mentioned. Can somebody please point towards an appropriate reference to gain relevant knowledge.

Thanks.